# Amazon RDS: Custom resolv.conf within EC2 breaks connectivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We override the default resolv.conf within our EC2 instance, replacing both the nameservers and the search. However, this seems to break connection with RDS. If I revert back to the default EC2 resolv.conf, everything works fine. I'm not much of a sysadmin, so I'm a bit unsure as to how to work around this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar issue and have used the "resolvconf" package (as its named in Ubuntu at least)

http://packages.debian.org/sid/resolvconf

To keep our custom changes in sync.

What it looks is happening is that an EC2 instance will do a DHCP refresh and even though EC2 says your internal IP wont change a by-product of this refresh is that it overwrites `/etc/resolv.conf` - there by frying any of your changes. If you use `resolvconf` and configure ITS configuration with your custom changes, then upon a refresh it will merge your changes plus what it gets from the DHCP and write it back to `/etc/resolv.conf` which preserves your customizations.

Works for us pretty well.